# Use of Spring 5.3 with Servlet 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm working on application which uses Spring Core in version 4.3.14 and Spring Web in version 4.2.13. We don't use Spring MVC. Also, from Spring Web we use just very limited set of classes:

- XmlWebApplicationContext (so classes from org.springframework.web.context)
- RestTemplate (so classes from org.springframework.web.client, here i expect some problems)
- some util classes which probably can be refactored to use something else

My question is:
We want to migrate to Spring 5.x. Is such a migration really possible? Or should i expect some severe problems with application startup (class incompatibilites etc). This source for example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#whats-new-in-version-50 says that Servlet 3.1 is required

From the other side, here https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/10/feedback-welcome-spring-5-system-requirements JUERGEN HOELLER wrote that migration to Spring 5 will be a soft one. So i assume that if Application uses only features from JEE6 + Servlet 3.0, then it can be that it will also work on Spring 5.x with JEE6-compatible appserver

Does anyone have an experience in that?

Answer (score 1):

As always, Spring Framework upgrades its baseline with new major versions. In this case, [we're requiring JDK8+ and Java EE7+](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#whats-new-in-version-50).

In practice, this means that the compiled code depends on those APIs and doesn't use reflection anymore to adapt to them. In your case, this is not only about Servlet, but also JPA, JMS, bean validation and other specs.

Your application might work fine with the arrangement you're mentioning, but the Spring team will not guarantee support for this setup.

Comment: There are other dependent frameworks i know. However other frameworks does not cause issues on Wepshere 8.5. There is just problem with Servlet 3.1.

Thx for clarification